# Van der Waals cycle calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation

> For the Van der Waals gas we get a cycle consisting of 2 isobaric and
>   2 isenthalpic processes.

We are given $T_1$,$T_3$ and $v_1$,$v_3$. And we want to calculate the
 efficiency.

**Attempt of solution:**

Well, for the heat calculation of isenthalpic part, we have:

$dH = TdS+Vdp=0$ and the heat is $dQ= -Vdp$

How can I express $dQ$ from the state equations? Especially $dp$? By differentation?

I was thinking about splitting the process into two: Isethermal and isochoric part.

I am interested in the isenthalpic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start out by determining the temperatures and specific volumes at points 2 and 4.  These could be obtained, for example, by setting the pressure change from point 1 to point 2 equal to zero, and the enthalpy change between points 2 and 3 equal to zero:
$$\frac{RT_1}{v_1-b}-\frac{a}{v_1^2}=\frac{RT_2}{v_2-b}-\frac{a}{v_2^2}$$and $$cRT_3-\frac{a}{v_3}+\left[\frac{RT_3}{v_3-b}-\frac{a}{v_3^2}\right]v_3=cRT_2-\frac{a}{v_2}+\left[\frac{RT_2}{v_2-b}-\frac{a}{v_2^2}\right]v_2$$
These provide two equations in the two knowns for $T_2$ and $v_2$.

The heat between points 1 and 2 could then be determined by:
$$U_2-U_1=cR(T_2-T_1)-\frac{a}{v_2}+\frac{a}{v_1}=Q_{1,2}-\left[\frac{RT_1}{v_1-b}-\frac{a}{v_1^2}\right](v_2-v_1)$$

Along the constant enthalpy line between points 2 and 3, the temperature and specific volume are related by:
$$cRT-\frac{a}{v}+\left[\frac{RT}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v^2}\right]v=cRT_2-\frac{a}{v_2}+\left[\frac{RT_2}{v_2-b}-\frac{a}{v_2^2}\right]v_2$$Solving for T along this line then gives T as a function of v:
$$T = \frac{cRT_2-\frac{a}{v_2}+\left[\frac{RT_2}{v_2-b}-\frac{a}{v_2^2}\right]v_2+2\frac{a}{v}}{cR+\frac{vR}{v-b}}$$
So, along this line, the pressure P is given by:
$$P=\frac{cRT_2-\frac{a}{v_2}+\left[\frac{RT_2}{v_2-b}-\frac{a}{v_2^2}\right]v_2+2\frac{a}{v}}{(c+1)v-cb}-\frac{a}{v^2}$$
and the heat $Q_{2,3}$ is given by:
$$cR(T_3-T_2)=Q_{2,3}-\int_{v_2}^{v_3}{\frac{cRT_2-\frac{a}{v_2}+\left[\frac{RT_2}{v_2-b}-\frac{a}{v_2^2}\right]v_2+2\frac{a}{v}}{(c+1)v-cb}dv}$$

Comment: Yes, I actually calculated this similarly. But the isenthalpic process is really hard and I can't see another way than evaluate that above mentioned integral. :/

Comment: I have searched everywhere on the internet. No example with van der waals and isenthalpic process.

Comment: See what I've added to my answer at the bottom, regarding the constant enthalpy segments.